# How to debug Storyshots test generation issues

Tags: jestjs, storybook, storyshots

I'm working on a project that uses Storybook with Storyshots addon. The Jest tests contain a crawler that generates tests based on Storybook stories. When test generation process goes wrong Jest tells me `Your test suite must contain at least one test.` Is there anyway to get more accurate information about what went wrong? At one point I might have a substantial amount of working tests and in the next moment one problematic story might take that back to zero.

See full error with stack trace below

```
 FAIL  ./storyshots.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:175:18)
      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:304:17
      at node_modules/emittery/index.js:260:13
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Emittery.Typed.emit (node_modules/emittery/index.js:258:23)
```

The `initStoryshots` call looks as follows

```
initStoryshots({
  framework: 'react',
  configPath: path.join(__dirname, '.storybook'),
  integrityOptions: { cwd: path.join(__dirname, 'src') },
  test: multiSnapshotWithOptions(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That message can be thrown for many reasons, try the --verbose option of jest for more feedback